# UIGesture Recognizer Crashes Application

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I was trying to add a UI Gesture Recognizer to my SKScene in Swift using the following

```
let recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

        func handleSwipe() {
            println("Swiped Right")
```

However, once I run and perform a swipe, the application crashed with the following log:

2014-11-22 23:21:35.251 Revolution[83866:460316] -[Revolution.levelSelect handleSwipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feec842b920
2014-11-22 23:21:35.255 Revolution[83866:460316] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Revolution.levelSelect handleSwipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feec842b920'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Is there anything I need to add into the GameViewController or what about the selector is causing it to crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ":" in "handleSwipe:" indicates that method `handleSwipe` takes an argument. In this case, a gesture object is passed to the gesture handler. So, your function should be

```
func handleSwipe(gesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    println("Swiped Right")
}
```

Comment: It still fails to run.  I have a feeling it has to do with the GameViewController. Should the UIGesturerecognizer be initialized there?

Comment: No, you should initialize it in `didMoveToView` in GameScene.m. Is `handleSwipe()` declared in `didMoveToView` as well? I can't tell from your post.

Comment: It is. 
`let recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        
        
func handleSwipe(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            println("Swiped Right")
        }`

Comment: You need to move `handleSwipe` out of the `didMoveToView` method.